# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am working on React js with Django Rest API. When I try to submit form data through api, it showing me the error. I think some null values are going to api and I dont know how to check them. I am new to react.js learning from on tutorial.Can anyone please teach me a way to debug this kind of issues.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
  22 |    this.setState({ btnMessage: 1 });
  23 | 
  24 |    var apiHandler = new APIHandler();
> 25 |    var response = await apiHandler.saveMedicineData(
     | ^  26 |      event.target.name.value,
  27 |      event.target.medical_typ.value,
  28 |      event.target.buy_price.value,
```

Here is my form code:

```
async formSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ btnMessage: 1 });
    
        var apiHandler = new APIHandler();
        var response = await apiHandler.saveMedicineData(
          event.target.name.value,
          event.target.medical_typ.value,
          event.target.buy_price.value,
          event.target.sell_price.value,
          event.target.c_gst.value,
          event.target.s_gst.value,
          event.target.batch_no.value,
          event.target.shelf_no.value,
          event.target.expire_date.value,
          event.target.mfg_date.value,
          event.target.company_id.value,
          event.target.description.value,
          event.target.in_stock_total.value,
          event.target.qty_in_strip.value,
          this.state.medicinedetails
        );
        
        this.setState({ btnMessage: 0 });
        this.setState({ errorRes: response.data.error });
        this.setState({ errorMessage: response.data.message });
        this.setState({ sendData: true });
      }
```

Below is the Api Handler:

```
async saveMedicineData(
        name,
        medical_typ,
        buy_price,
        sell_price,
        c_gst,
        s_gst,
        batch_no,
        shelf_no,
        expire_date,
        mfg_date,
        company_id,
        description,
        in_stock_total,
        qty_in_strip,
        medicinedetails
      ) {
        await this.checkLogin();
        //Wait Until Token Get Updated
    
        var response = await Axios.post(
          Config.medicineApiUrl,
          {
            name: name,
            medical_typ: medical_typ,
            buy_price: buy_price,
            sell_price: sell_price,
            c_gst: c_gst,
            s_gst: s_gst,
            batch_no: batch_no,
            shelf_no: shelf_no,
            expire_date: expire_date,
            mfg_date: mfg_date,
            company_id: company_id,
            description: description,
            in_stock_total: in_stock_total,
            qty_in_strip: qty_in_strip,
            medicine_details: medicinedetails,
          },
          { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + AuthHandler.getLoginToken() } }
        );
    
        return response;
      }
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information to know more about the issue.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For getting value use  `event.target.value` instead of `event.target.name.value`